# Save a webpage completely

Tags: html, css, web, local

I have a small problem that concerns an outsourced website development company who will not (for perfectly normal and valid reason) allow us access to the server to alter stylesheets. I've been tasked to redesign a website layout. Problem is, I cannot access the website nor a dev environment to alter the stylesheets to bring forth these ideas. Only route to this would be to create a local custom.css to send via email to the person who uploads them. However, I cannot in good faith just throw them a CSS file to be applied on a live site without fully cross-browser checking it and I cannot do this locally on IE, Safari or Opera.

One solution was to save the website locally as HTML (file, save as...) but the problem is the background CMS is complete crap, meaning it has like 200 completely unnescessary CSS files and it is organized as:

**main.css** has 7 @import rules with relative paths.

Inside this is another stylesheet with 16 @import rules with relative paths.

Inside this... You get the picture.

This would mean I would have to shift through these 200 import rules and files to download them manually via the address bar. So my question is:

**How can I save this website as HTML to my computer to apply a custom user stylesheet file to it so I can cross-browser test it properly?** Is there some website that can go through a site and compress all the CSS to one file or smth?

Comment: I'd use something like https://www.npmjs.org/package/prosthetic which creates a proxy server on your local machine and can intercept the HTML and inject your additional CSS file. You can test this local URL using any browser.

Comment: Saving is also possible with wget. See http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget: `wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --domains website.org --no-parent www.website.org/tutorials/html/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download a whole website with dependencies using programs like HTTrack
http://www.httrack.com/

It allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML, images, and other files from the server to your computer. HTTrack arranges the original site's relative link-structure. Simply open a page of the "mirrored" website in your browser, and you can browse the site from link to link, as if you were viewing it online. HTTrack can also update an existing mirrored site, and resume interrupted downloads. HTTrack is fully configurable, and has an integrated help system.

WinHTTrack is the Windows 2000/XP/Vista/Seven release of HTTrack, and WebHTTrack the Linux/Unix/BSD release.

It doesn't consolidate all the CSS files into one, but it is better to retain the files as-is if you want to minimize changes